# stl: задание произвольных временных промежутков

Tags: c++, c++11, время, stl, std-chrono

Подскажите, где-то видел реализацию, а сейчас не могу найти:

возможность задавать время как параметр с указанием единицы измерения, например

```
myfunc(10ms);
myfunc(3h);
```

и т.д.

а также перевода указанных значений в секунды (причем не только целочисленные. например 0.17, если указано 17ms)

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void myFunc(const std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, 1>>& duration)
{
    std::cout << "duration is: " << duration.count() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    myFunc(1ms);
    myFunc(1s);
    myFunc(1min);
    myFunc(1h);

    system("pause");
}
```

Вывод:

```
duration is: 0.001
duration is: 1
duration is: 60
duration is: 3600
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio

Comment: `using namespace std::chrono_literals` добавь, а то не заработает...